# How can I make this React useEffect hook work without excluding some dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a condesandbox recreating this issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-tree-dq8rx?file=/src/App.js

The sandbox recreates the functionality of a component that shows a list of empty image preview thumbnails which can be selected.

The image thumbnail of the currently selected image is updated when a user uploads an image and a `downloadUrl` is returned. The `useEffect` hook has a dependency on `downloadUrl` so it is called each time a new image has been uploaded and a `downloadUrl` returned. I have imitated this functionality with a button that returns a new URL each time it is clicked.

If I include the full list of dependencies, the `downloadUrl` is immediately applied to the next zone that is clicked on. This is not what I desire. I want to be able to select the next image thumbnail and assign it a different `downloadUrl`. This only works as desired if I exclude the 'project' and 'selectedZoneIndex' dependencies.

I have attempted to resolve this by using a `useReducer` hook and a dispatch function. This succeeds in removing the dependency however the result of the dispatch function isn't available inside the `useEffect` hook so I can't use the new object to update the project. I have made an example of this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sara-ofoh1?file=/src/App.js (newProject is `undefined` in the console)

I would appreciate any advice on how to solve this problem while following best practices (not excluding dependencies that should be included).

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const onUpdateProject = async (newProject) => {
    try {
      await updateDatabase(newProject)
      return "updated"
    } catch (error) {
      return "error"
    }
  }
  if (downloadUrl) {
    setSelectedZoneImageUrl(downloadUrl);

    // Update Zone with downloadUrl
    const updatedZones = zones.slice();
    updatedZones[selectedZoneIndex]["imageDownloadUrl"] = downloadUrl;

    // Create new project with updated zone
    const newProject = {
      ...project,
      zones: updatedZones,
    };

   onUpdateProject(newProject);
  }
}, [downloadUrl, selectedZoneIndex, project, zones])
```

Comment: I tried your first sandbox and [printed all the dependencies](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-silence-lr8di?file=/src/App.js). I see `project` being successfully passed to `useEffect`. On the other hand, there's a infinite loop as it triggers `updateServer`. If I then change zone, the url is instantly applied. Is that the problem?

Comment: Your comment made me realise that the `onUpdateProject` and `updateDatabase` aren't necessary to demonstrate the problem. In my actual app I use the result of the useEffect hook in an async function call so I tried to imitate that for demonstrating the problem with using `dispatch`. I have removed them from my examples and the infinite loop is gone but the issue of the url being applied instantly remains. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you don't need a `useEffect` at all. Maybe your actual use case makes this infeasible, but your original code sample seems to work as intended if you get rid of the effect and place all the logic into the `newDownloadUrl` handler. There's no need to react to the state change if it's all happening in once place.

I also spotted another issue with the way you are handling the `zones` array - since it is an array of objects, you need to clone each object individually otherwise they will retain their reference. Your state was being mutated before the setter was called in `updateDatabase`:

```
const newDownloadUrl = () => {
    const onUpdateProject = async newProject => {
      try {
        await updateDatabase(newProject);
        return "updated";
      } catch (error) {
        return "error";
      }
    };

    const newUrl = "www." + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + ".com";
    setDownloadUrl(newUrl);
    setSelectedZoneImageUrl(newUrl);

    // Update Zone with downloadUrl
    const updatedZones = zones.slice().map(z => ({...z}));
    updatedZones[selectedZoneIndex]["imageDownloadUrl"] = newUrl;

    // Create new project with updated zone
    const newProject = {
      ...project,
      zones: updatedZones
    };

    onUpdateProject(newProject);
  };
```

Comment: I don't think I can use this approach. The useEffect is needed because in my real app the `downloadUrl` is a value returned by a custom hook that is called by another component. The `newDownloadUrl` button was just my attempt to recreate that functionality in the sandbox, where the useEffect is called for each new `downloadUrl`. Thanks for the advice about mutating the state.